# Transfer RPC 401 Unauthorized

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transfer

i got error again when transfer via walletRPC.php from https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp result is : Response Http Error - 401 Unauthorized ,it's only for transfer function, if i used another function like getbalance , getaddress or another it is working fine.

when i used command line with curl it's waiting so long but working.

Thank you

update :
Log from monero rpc

wallet2 src/wallet/wallet2.h:1847 amount=0.283566590000, real_output=10, real_output_in_tx_index=0, indexes: xxxxx 2019-05-08 02:48:30.361 [RPC0] WARN wallet.wallet2 src/wallet/wallet2.h:1847 amount=0.283566590000, real_output=10, real_output_in_tx_index=0, indexes: xx 2019-05-08 02:49:40.818 [RPC0] WARN wallet.wallet2 src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1628 Received money: 0.283432780000, with tx:

**i call on 02:48:30 but the result respond its so long 02:49:40, takes time 1 minutes , how to make the result faster ? i think thats the problem response http error 401 unauthorized**

update 2 :

i see problem from this github https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/4606 
in there the guidance is upgrade the machine, i've already upgraded to ssd but still same.

Comment: Please add the example code you are using to call the transfer method.

Comment: i used monerophp in github, in monerophp source code call the Auth first with walletRPC(user,pass,ip,port), after that i call for transfer function in source transfer(amount,address,payment_id)  , the result json is Response Http Error - 401 Unauthorized but the transfer is successfull.

Comment: Log from monero rpc

wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.h:1847       amount=0.283566590000, real_output=10, real_output_in_tx_index=0, indexes: xxxxx
2019-05-08 02:48:30.361 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.h:1847       amount=0.283566590000, real_output=10, real_output_in_tx_index=0, indexes: xx
2019-05-08 02:49:40.818 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1628     Received money: 0.283432780000, with tx: <f079124891af04cde844cf2b88a50f635d3b75656766a178734feb56a9dc2d6c>

**i call on 02:48:30 but the result its so long 02:49:40**

Comment: Please update the question with these details, not paste as comments. Adding them in the question allows you to format and make more readable. Further, your log message is *receiving* not sending.

Comment: please help my problem same like https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/4606

Comment: Are you using the latest release? Version 0.13.0.4?

Comment: i using 0.14.0.2 still waiting so long